# Azure Mobile Service Connection Strings following v12 upgrade

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

So Azure upgraded our server/database to v12.

The mobile service (javascript version) has not had it's 'MS_TableConnectionString' updated, and it is not editable in the portal.

Is there any way to edit/replace the connection string?

I see there is a change database button on the mobile service in the portal.......should we use that to repoint at the same (all be it v12 with new connection string) database? Will our tables get recreated/duplicated?

BTW: The web app service did update itself - well it works anyway

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the 'change database' button resolved the error. As in the client can now retrieve database data via the mobile service.

BUT viewing the MS_TableConnectionString within the portal still shows the old connection string not the new one!